# Finding the right selector for styling

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm having a hard time finding the right selector to apply a text color to.

The problem is that I only want to change the background and font color for the menu widgets and not all the widget on the blog page. I was able to change the background color to the specific sidebar by using

```
body.page-id-41350 .content aside.sidebar .widget
```

But can't for the life of me find the right one for the font color. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://kelleyadv.com/kelleyadvnewsitetest/?page_id=41350

Comment: try this: `nav.main_menu > ul > li > a` Change `background-color` and `color` properties.

Comment: Could you not simply create a new class for them?

Comment: Uauuu..you are miles away...;) The condition is to put on the div...not in the code of woocommerce...lol...You don´t read my comments...you must put here: <aside class="sidebar  (put here the condition)">

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditions

**INLINE**

```
<div style="<?php if( the_title == 'about'){ echo 'color: green';}else{ echo 'color: red';} ?>">Your text color change</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<div class="<?php if( the_title == 'about'){ echo 'green';}else{ echo 'red';} ?>">Your text color change</div>
```

Comment: So I've put the conditional statement within the aside.sidebar div but its just echoing in words. I know this is something simple but I'm still learning php... I guess this is a good op to learn something. What is my next move here?

Comment: Ok...i hope that was the CSS condition, right? What you see? debug code: <aside class="sidebar red">...do you see red or green?

Comment: I see that you put outside de div and it was the inline. Put css and on the div ex: <aside class="sidebar  (your condition here)">

Comment: Be sure of your the_title(); page...this is the anchor

Comment: well with the condition it echos red

Comment: Because the title page? What is the title page? put this code on the page that you want the change color ?php the_title();?> . this will give you the title of the  page. Put is the same place where you put the condition because i want to see the title of the page, please

Comment: OK i've edited my question with what I have in the sidebar.php file. I may be in the complete wrong file. I'm definitely treading outside my knowledge base.

Comment: 1 - You must to know the title of the page where you want to make  the condition - <?php the_title(); ?> -> this show the title . 2- Adapt the condition based on the title name. It´s very simple :)

Comment: ok i see what you are saying... sorry. title is About. Still seems to be echoing red though. edit:  I know this is very simple php and I feel dumb haha.

Comment: Beware of the case sensitive...put the title  capitalize too in the condition

Comment: it´s so simple...you must have the same title in the condition... Just play it with...you will find the right way

Comment: yea I changed the case.

Comment: Instead of the title , use the slug (avoid errors)...use this code to get the slug:  <?php global $post; $theslug = $post->post_name;  echo $theslug;?>  And the after you see the slug you can delete the echo $theslug in the previous code and put the variable in the condition to make the match

Answer (score 0):

They're links right? So, just like you did the last bit, add an `a` for anchor tag

```
body.page-id-41350 .content aside.sidebar .widget a {   color: #fff; }
```

Comment: I ended up doing this for every page. I'm sure there might have been an easier solution via php but this worked too.